# Fill in values in XML Template

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have xml templates stored in files where there are values to be filled are written as  lets say following for example

```
<customers>
  <customer>
  <name><%=user.name%></name>
  <street><%=user.address.street%></street>
  </customer>
</customers>
```

I will have user object filled in and will load this xml in string . Is there any easy way to replace related values in entire file easily ? Please consider that above is just sample and XML is really complicated with lot of constants in it and I cant use XML serialization to convert object in to XML .

Thanks

Comment: Is there any kind of dynamic repetition or looping necessary? Have you looked at Xml Transformations? Look at [Slow Cheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5). You can use it to write a simple XML with your values, then execute the transform to make the more complicated XML result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple regex can help here

```
var newXml = Regex.Replace(xml, "<%=(.+?)%>", m => MyFxn(m.Groups[1].Value));

//replace this function with yours which returns the real values. It's
//just a demo.... 
string MyFxn(string s)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
        {"user.name","name1"},
        {"user.address.street","street1"}
    };

    return dict[s];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to find your data-binding expressions and replace them with values obtained using `DataBinder.Eval` (in ASP.NET) or through reflection from corresponding properties of your object (http://programmersunlimited.wordpress.com/2010/06/19/reflection-get-property-value-from-path/).